# Change button title based on text in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4.2

im trying to change the button title based on the text selection in the tableview but somehow the error "invalid escape sequence in literal" always pop up.can someone help me to solve this?Thanks!!

Below is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = userList[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    btnDrop.setTitle("\|userList[indexPath.row|", for: .normal)
    animate(toogle: false)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your case `userList` contains strings, which means that there is no need to do a string interpolation. You could use it directly:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    btnDrop.setTitle(userList[indexPath.row], for: .normal)
    animate(toogle: false)
}
```

---

However, the reason of the error is: when doing a string interpolation you should do it like this:

```
"\(userList[indexPath.row)"
```

instead of:

```
"\|userList[indexPath.row|"
```

`()` instead of `||`.

For more information, check [Swift Programming Language: Strings and Characters](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html) - String Interpolation section.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add any printable value to string, you can use string interpolation:

`\(value)`

So replace this

```
btnDrop.setTitle("\|userList[indexPath.row|", for: .normal)
```

with this

```
btnDrop.setTitle("\(userList[indexPath.row])", for: .normal)
```

But in your case you don't have to use it because your userList is just array of string values so you can simply use this:

```
btnDrop.setTitle(userList[indexPath.row], for: .normal)
```